# Multi-module project structure Maven

Tags: maven

I have a project that contains 2 applications and a core which will be contained in both which handles things like database access. I have a separate module for each application but I's not sure if I should use another module for the core or put it in the parent module.

```
Project+-+-+src                            
         |                                 
         +-+App1                           
         |                                 
         +-+App2
```

or using a seperate module:

```
Project+-+-+Core                           
         |                                 
         +-+App1                           
         |                                 
         +-+App2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Core` as a separate module and have `App1` and `App2` depend on it. You can manage the dependency in the parent POM:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    ...
```

Dependency tree:

```
Project+-+-+-+Core                           
         |                                 
         +-+-+App1   
         | |
         | +-+-+Core                        
         |                                 
         +-+-+App2
           |
           +-+-+Core
```

See [this link from the Maven project page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) for dependency management.

Comment: I am assuming that Project is the parent module and Core, App2 and App2 are all children of it? Is there a convention when naming a parent module as the project is called "core" and I have a "core" module.

Comment: Yes that's what the above hierarchy implies. For the naming conventions, you can choose whatever name for the parent project other than `core` to avoid any conflict. You can also check http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html.